# What HTML tags may contain javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser

I was wondering what elements can contain javascript code in their attributes? I know that it's allowed in link "href" (javascript://) and all on* attributes.

Do browsers execute javascript code from any other attributes?

Comment: You're asking for "[tag:security]". What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html and search for `%Script;`. The only attributes are the `on*` attributes.

Comment: There next to href is "%URI". so that means that any attributes that are "%URI" may contain javascript? like background attribute from body or cite from blockquotes?

Comment: @thelolcat: Next to `href` on anchors/areas I've found `form`s to execute `javascript`-pseudoprotocol-URIs in their `action` attribute for example. It doesn't work for all `%URI` attributes though, e.g. a `img` `src`

Comment: @thelolcat it would help people help you if you would describe what you're *really* trying to do.  JavaScript in tag attributes is generally a bad, old-fashioned practice.

Answer (score 2):

It's *allowed* in `href` because that's what gets put into your browser address bar. Similarly you can use something like:

```
document.location.href = 'javascript:alert("hello");';
```

There isn't really a good reason to put JavaScript in `href` though. It's very limited in it's usefulness. I would suggest the proper route of onclick handlers or some setup that reacts to changes in the `#` (hash).